# Convert plink .ped separate nucleotides format to slash genotypes format using sed

Tags: sed, plink

I am trying to use LDheatmap library in R. The matrix of genotypes required must be in the format A/T T/C G/G etc ... to be imported as a dataframe.

Starting from a .ped plink file, I used SED for the text transformation.
I needed to replace one every other white space with a `/` (forward slash). This might be useful to someone.

From:

```
 loc1 loc2 loc3 loc4 loc5
ind-1 A A T C T C A G G C
ind-2 A A T G T C A C G C
ind-3 A A C T T C A C G C
ind-4 C A T T T G A C G C
ind-5 A A C T T C A C G C
ind-6 A T C G T C A C G C
```

To:

```
 loc1 loc2 loc3 loc4 loc5
ind-1 A/A T/C T/C A/G G/C
ind-2 A/A T/G T/C A/C G/C
ind-3 A/A C/T T/C A/C G/C
ind-4 C/A T/T T/G A/C G/C
ind-5 A/A C/T T/C A/C G/C
ind-6 A/T C/G T/C A/C G/C
```

I used sed:

```
sed '2,${s/\(\s.\) \(.\)/\1\/\2/g}' pedfile > newfile
```

I arrived to this result a little by chance, so I will try to decode the sed line to be sure my interpretation is correct:

`2,$`: start the script,contained between `{ }`, from the beginning to the end of the line of the file.

`s/`: substitute.

`\(\s.\)`: first block, contains one white space followed by any single character (nucleotide).

`\(.\)`: second block, preceded by a white space outside of the block, contains one single character.

`\1\/\2`: concatenate block \1 and block \2 with a forward slash /. the forward slash need to be set as textual by using a preceding \ to exit the regex syntax.

`/g`: apply the regex code to all the following lines.

**Question**: Is my interpretation correct here or am I missing something?

Comment: 2 details are ambiguous. the slash in `\/` does not escape regex syntax, it avoids `/` to be interpreted as delimiter of the command. note : instead of writing `s/a\/b/c\/d/`, you can write `s:a/b:c/d:`. Secondly `/g` apply the replacement to all occurences on each line; otherwise it applies only to 1st occurence.

Comment: @ArnoBozo wouldn't your comment make a nice answer?

Comment: The better would be an edition of Gogol question. I found too "talky" to write an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Thank you anyway Arno Bozo. It was useful.